# How can I add types to express Response that flow down to added middleware which restricts the response structure?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to add types to express to control what the response structure can be, but I can't figure out how to lift the `<TestData>` up higher such as putting it at the `router.get<TestData>()` level. Is there a way to specify it at that level and have typescript infer it when calling `res.wrap`?

```
import express from 'express';

interface Wrap<Data> {
    time: number;
    data: Data;
}
interface TestData {
    foo: string;
}
type AnyResp = TestData | FooData | BarData | ...

function promiseHandler(handler) {
    return function(req, res) {
        try {
            const result = handler(req, res).catch(next);
        } catch(err) {
            next(err);
        }
    }
}

const app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.wrap = function<T extends AnyResp>(data: T) {
        const wrapped: Wrap<T> = {
            time: 123,
            data: data,
        };
        res.json(wrapped);
    };
    next();
});

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/test', promiseHandler(async function(req, res) {
    // Is it possible to move this higher and infer it?
    res.wrap<TestData>({
        foo: 'bar',
    });
}));

app.use(router);
```